# How to calculate the first date from a category excluding subcategory?

Tags: count, dax, measure

I would like to calculate the first date of the project, a kind of minimum. When I use MINX, everything is fine, but when I want to count how many projects have this minimum date are in Jan-2024, it doesn't calculate correctly.

[This is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEIzs.png) 
I used the following measure to get the minimum date of each project

minDate= MINX(Table 1, Table 1 [Date])

Then, I counted the project which have the minimum date "Jan-2024"

Count minDate from Jan-2024 =
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Project),
FILTER(Table 1, MONTH(minDate)=MONTH(TODAY())),
FILTER(Table 1,YEAR(minDate)=YEAR(TODAY()))

[For Project 2 it's counting me 1 because Romania has a date from January, but it should pe zero, because the minimum date is 01/12/2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntenx.png)

Somehow I would like to get rid of Country in my measure.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Count minDate from Jan-2024 = 
  var sTbl = SUMMARIZE('Table 1', 'Table 1'[Project], "minDate", [minDate])
  return 
    CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT('Table 1'[Project]),
      FILTER(
        sTbl,
        MONTH([minDate]) = MONTH(TODAY()) && 
        YEAR([minDate]) = YEAR(TODAY())
      )
    )
```